# OpenAPI Generator basepath is prefixed with host when using sprinv-mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi-generator

In my current setup I have a swagger yaml where I need to create SpringMVC controller class and Java model classes.
My yaml looks like this:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: some description
  version: 1.0.0
  title: My API Name
  contact:
    name: name
    url: https://domain.tld
    email: email@domain.tld
host: api.domain.tld
basePath: /v1
tags: []
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /myendpoint:
    get:
```

The problem is that the basePath is being ignored.
In the generated api I am getting this:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/myendpoint"},
    produces = {"application/json"},
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
```

And I am expecting this:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/v1//myendpoint"},
    produces = {"application/json"},
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
```

I am aware of the existence of the template variable *{{basePath}}*, however when I print the output of this variable, I get the host including the basePath which looks like this:
***https://domain.tld/v1***.

Is there a way that I can get the basePath as is defined in my *swagger.yaml*?